# cannot create multiple directories with makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

What is wrong with this statement in my makefile?

`folder:
  @mkdir -vp ".cache/vim/"{backup,swap}`

I can run `mkdir -vp ".cache/vim/"{backup,swap}` on the commandline and it does exactly what it is supposed to do, ie. creating two folders, backup and swap.

But for the when i run `make folder` with the above code, it literally create a folder name `{backup,swap}`

Comment: Why would you expect `make` to duplicate [bash brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, all versions of `make` use `/bin/sh`, not `bash`, for shell commands, while in most situations `bash` is the interactive shell you use from the command line. This explains why brace expansion, a `bash` feature absent in `sh`, works in the latter case but not in the former.

If you want to keep your makefiles portable to the highest degree, your only option is to write the command in full:

```
folder:
        @mkdir -vp '.cache/vim/backup' '.cache/vim/swap'
```

However, if you want to use features of GNU `make` (available for every platform in existence, but not necessarily installed by default) you can use the `addprefix` function in a way similar to this:

```
# Quotes aren’t necessary in this case, this is just to show how to use them
BASEDIR = './cache/vim'
FILES   = 'backup' 'swap'

folder:
        @mkdir -vp $(addprefix $(BASEDIR)/,$(FILES))
```

Or you can instruct GNU `make` to use `/bin/bash` and use the same command you use on the command line:

```
SHELL   = /bin/bash
BASEDIR = './cache/vim'

folder:
        @mkdir -vp $(BASEDIR)/{backup,swap}
```

A discussion on how GNU make uses the `SHELL` variable can be found [here.](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html)

Answer (score 2):

[make](/questions/tagged/make) is not [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), so brace expansions will not work, so :

```
folder:
  @mkdir -vp '.cache/vim/backup' '.cache/vim/backupswap'
```